# How can we figure out that a column in my oracle table is being populated/updated by a trigger of another table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Consider a scenario, where there are two tables "A" and "B".

Table "A" has a trigger "Ta" [written long before me joining this project and thus I'm completely unaware of the trigger], which updates a column named "colB" in table "B".

Now, since I'm mostly using table "B" and concerned about the way "colB" is getting, I won't know if trigger "Ta" is updating this column.

So my question is, is there a direct oracle query/way to find if a column in one table is getting updated by any trigger running on another table?

Thanks in advance for educating me on this.

Regards
a.b

Comment: What's stopping you from looking at the code for the trigger and seeing if it updates table B?

Comment: Look at "used by" tab of table B properties in your favorite database tool (mine is Toad).

Answer (score 2):

Oracle fine grained dependency tracking knows which columns are used.  Unfortunately, there is no way to track if that dependency is for reading or writing.  And there is no default `DBA_DEPENDENCY_COLUMNS` view to find this information.

But luckily [Rob van Wijk](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2008/10/dbadependencycolumns.html) has created such a view.  His blog has some more information, including the grants and `create view` statement, about half-way down the page.

Example:

```
drop table a;
drop table b;

create table a(colA number);
create table b(colB number, read_only number, not_used number);

create or replace trigger Ta
after update or insert or delete on a
begin
    update b set colB = read_only;
end;
/

--What triggers are referencing B's columns?
select owner, name, type, referenced_column
from dba_dependency_columns
where referenced_owner = user
    and referenced_name = 'B'
    and type = 'TRIGGER';

OWNER    NAME  TYPE     REFERENCED_COLUMN
-----    ----  ----     -----------------
JHELLER  TA    TRIGGER  COLB
JHELLER  TA    TRIGGER  READ_ONLY
```

The view uses several undocumented tables and some advanced SQL features.  This view would not be a good idea on a production server.  But it is probably much more accurate than any solution that involves parsing SQL.

Comment: Thanks gurus for all your kind help. Appreciate this :-)!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    user_sources
WHERE
    type = 'TRIGGER'
AND UPPER(text) LIKE '%UPDATE A%';
```

But it won't work if the query is in two lines such as :

```
UPDATE
    A
SET
   ...
```

because `text` matches to a given line in the corresponding object.

Comment: `select * from user_source where ... and regexp_like(text,'update[^[:alnum:]]a','i')`, or, just look at that specific trigger...

Comment: he says he'd like to suppose he doesn't know the trigger

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
create table table_a(
 id number primary key,
 val varchar2( 100 )
);

create table table_b(
 len number
);

insert into table_b values ( 0 );

set define off
create or replace trigger after_table_a
after insert on table_a for each row
begin
   UpDate 
     table_B
       set len = len + length( :new.val );
end;
/

insert into table_a values ( 1, 'Ala ma kota');
insert into table_a values ( 2, 'As to ali pies');
commit;

select * from table_b;

       LEN
----------
        25
```

And the query:

```
select trigger_name, 
       regexp_substr( trigger_body, 'update\s+table_b',1,1,'i') update_command
from (
  select ut.trigger_name, 
         dbms_metadata.GET_DDL('TRIGGER', ut.trigger_name) trigger_body 
  from user_dependencies ud
  join user_triggers ut on ( ud.type = 'TRIGGER' 
                             and ut.trigger_name = ud.name 
                             and ut.table_name <> ud.referenced_name )
  where ud.referenced_name = 'TABLE_B'
)
where regexp_instr( trigger_body, 'update\s+table_b',1,1,0,'i') > 0 ;


TRIGGER_NAME  UPDATE_COMMAND
------------- ------------------ 
AFTER_TABLE_A UpDate
                table_B
```