# Query or method to find out packages depending on a particular column of a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have to change the name and the datatype of a column of a table. I have about 200++ packages in the Oracle 11g database. How can find the name of all the packages which are dependent on this column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we figure out that a column in my oracle table is being populated/updated by a trigger of another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764739/how-can-we-figure-out-that-a-column-in-my-oracle-table-is-being-populated-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to look into `all_dependencies` view to check what all objects are using your table.

```
select * from all_dependencies 
where referenced_name = '<table_name_in_upper_case>';
```

But this does not tell you what columns are being used.

You'll have to look into `all_source` for that.

```
select distinct type, name 
from all_source 
where upper(text) like '<column_name_in_upper_case>'
and name in (
            select name 
            from all_dependencies 
            where referenced_name = '<table_name_in_upper_case>'
            );
```

However this may give you false positives, if the column name is generic.

Also, `all_source` won't show you any views that might be using this column name. You will have to look into `all_views` or use

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','view_name_in_upper_case','owner_in_upper_case')
FROM dual
```